# How can I find the Min and max of this question?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

I have been trying for the past 2 hours on this question and cannot seem to figure out the answer. So far I have gotten the 'green' bits correct. Someone Help please

[image]

Comment: The partials are not both $0$ in the *interior*. So you need to study the two one variable functions $x^3-7x^2-49x-343$ and a simpler linear one, for $x$ between $-\sqrt{53}$ and $\sqrt{53}$.